# Copying few bits of one variable into another

Tags: python, variables, bit-manipulation, concatenation

I have a variable say A that stores 1101 0010 . But I want to just copy the first 5 bits into another variable say B. Also I want to concatenate some bits from another variable to variable B. 
Basically if A = 1101 0010 then B = 11010 (just taking first 5 bits from A)
 and C = 1101 0111  (adding 111 to the already existing bits in B)

How to implement this in Python ?

Comment: This isn't very clear.  Do you always want to replace lowest 3 bits with 111 or something else?

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the A var is a string, you'll have to slice it then concatenate it.

Here is an example :

```
>>> a = '11010 0010'
>>> b = a[0:5]
>>> b
'11010'
>>> c = b + '111'
>>> c = int(c,2)
>>> c
215
>>> bin(c)
'0b11010111'
```

Comment: Did OP say data was a string?

Comment: I guest it is because of the space.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks you @joel

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
>>> a=int('11010010', 2)
>>> temp=int('11111000', 2)
>>> b=(a&temp)
>>> c=int('11010111', 2)
>>> temp1=c&int('00000111', 2)
>>> b=b|temp1
>>> b
215
>>> bin(b)
'0b11010111'
```

Comment: FWIW, you can specify integer literals in binary notation, eg `0b11010010`.

Comment: Oops, didnt know that, just used it for the first time for this question. Thanks.:)